# How to open an exe file in java

Tags: java, exe

I am trying to use java to open an exe file. I'm not sure which program I want to open so I am using Skype as an example. When I try to do it, it gives me errors.

```
 try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Skype\\Phone\\Skype");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

error:
Cannot run program "C:\Program": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Please post the error messages.

Comment: I added the error in an edit.

Comment: the path cant be wrong , u checked right ?

Comment: It doesnt help if i add the .exe at the end. the same error comes up

Comment: Looks suspiciously like "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : i dont think extension is required for .exe or .bat

Comment: the path is also correct

Comment: Note how the error says `Cannot run program "C:\Program"`. It looks like the first space is causing it to stop parsing the path.

Comment: @RomanVottner and ajp have your answer. I've deleted my prior incorrect answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
String path = "/path/to/my_app.exe";
File file = new File(path);
if (! file.exists()) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("The file " + path + " does not exist");
}
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a string array, change to

```
try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: yep this is the solution , +1

Comment: Are the spaces supposed to be escaped with `/` instead of the normal escape character ``\`` ?

Comment: @user2947797 try the new one I just posted

Comment: I don't think using the overloaded version `Runtime.exec(String[])` is going to help the space issue.

Comment: If the `String[]` method works, and the `String` method doesn't, that implies some sort of difference in implementation with how the executable is loaded between the two methods, which is just awful. I wonder if the OpenJDK environment (or any other Java implementations) has this same behavior, or if the spec says something about differences in behavior with these two methods.

Answer (score 1):

You are on windows so you have to include the extension .exe

```
 try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone/Skype.exe");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Maybe use `File.separator` instead of '\'

Comment: you don't need to add extension for .exe or .bat files

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it works fine, it's taken from your example. Pay attention to the double `\\`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Process p;
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_05\\bin\\Jconsole.exe");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try {
     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\ProgramFiles(x86)\\Skype\\Phone\\Skype");
} catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Because I think it doesn't allow for spaces, I know I'm a little bit late but it might help people in the future. Mabye do as another user suggested and add ".exe" to the end where it says "\skype" so it says `skype.exe` instead of just "skype"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no folder named `ProgramFiles(x86)` on Windows, so I doubt whether your "suggestion" will succeed. But I suggest to you not to post answers to questions unless you are sure that the answer is correct and does resolve the posted problem.